# Multiple condition on same column mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccfe06e2434de5c345d058e"),
        "user_id" : 1,
    "event" : "eventA",
    "channel_id" : "1098",
    "channel_node_id" : "2177",
    "channel_name" : "New work",
    "created_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "user_raw_data" : {
        "Name" : "akhilesh",
        "Mobile" : "1234567890",
        "Email" : "akhilesh@test.com"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccfe06e2434de5c345d058e"),
        "user_id" : 1
    "event" : "eventB,
    "channel_id" : "1098",
    "channel_node_id" : "2177",
    "channel_name" : "New work",
    "created_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "user_raw_data" : {
        "Name" : "akhilesh",
        "Mobile" : "1234567890",
        "Email" : "akhilesh@test.com"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccfe06e2434de5c345d058e"),
        "user_id" : 1
    "event" : "eventC,
    "channel_id" : "1098",
    "channel_node_id" : "2178",
    "channel_name" : "New work",
    "created_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "user_raw_data" : {
        "Name" : "akhilesh",
        "Mobile" : "1234567890",
        "Email" : "akhilesh@test.com"
}
,
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccfe06e2434de5c345d058e"),
        "user_id" : 2
    "event" : "eventA,
    "channel_id" : "1098",
    "channel_node_id" : "2178",
    "channel_name" : "New work",
    "created_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "user_raw_data" : {
        "Name" : "akhilesh",
        "Mobile" : "1234567890",
        "Email" : "akhilesh@test.com"
}
```

Now I want to get the count of events performed by the user so far. For eventA count will be 2, for eventB 1, and for eventC is 1. But this query will have multiple conditions so my condition is getting the count only if the user has performed (eventA or eventB) and eventC. So in that case from above doc user id 2 event will not be considered because they have not performed (eventA or eventB)

Also along with event match with mutiple and or condition I also want to apply filter on user_raw_data so my query should be like this

```
 db.web_channel_events.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "channel_id": "1098",
      "channel_node_id": "2177"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "user_id": "$user_id",
        "event": "$event"
      },
      "count": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id.user_id",
      "event_details": {
        $push: {
          "k": "$_id.event",
          "v": "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            {
              "event_details.k": "eventA",
              "event_details.v": {
                "$gte": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "event_details.k": "eventB",
              "event_details.v": {
                "$gte": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "event_details.k": "eventC",
          "event_details.v": {
            "$gte": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "user_raw_data.Name": "akhilesh"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$event_details"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$event_details.k",
      "count": {
        $sum: "$event_details.v"
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "user_id":"$user_id",
                "event":"$event"
            },
            "user_id":{
                $first:"$user_id"
            },
            "event":{
                $first:"$event"
            },
            "count":{
                $sum:1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$user_id",
            "user_id":{
                $first:"$user_id"
            },
            "event_details":{
                $push:{
                    "k":"$event",
                    "v":"$count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "event_details":{
                $arrayToObject:"$event_details"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
            $and:[
                {
                    $or:[
                        {
                            "event_details.eventA":{
                                $gt:0
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "event_details.eventB":{
                                $gt:0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "event_details.eventC":{
                        $gt:0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "eventA":{
                $sum:"$event_details.eventA"
            },
            "eventB":{
                $sum:"$event_details.eventB"
            },
            "eventC":{
                $sum:"$event_details.eventC"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "event_details.eventA":"$eventA",
            "event_details.eventB":"$eventB",
            "event_details.eventC":"$eventC"   
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccfe06e2434de5c345d0588"),
    "event" : "eventA",
    "user_id" : 1,
    "created_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8b132388edcf85b0aaa609"),
    "event" : "eventA",
    "user_id" : 1,
    "created_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8b132388edcf85b0aaa60a"),
    "event" : "eventB",
    "user_id" : 1,
    "created_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8b132388edcf85b0aaa60b"),
    "event" : "eventC",
    "user_id" : 1,
    "created_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8b132388edcf85b0aaa60c"),
    "event" : "eventC",
    "user_id" : 1,
    "created_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8b132388edcf85b0aaa60d"),
    "event" : "eventC",
    "user_id" : 2,
    "created_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000"),
    "updated_at" : NumberLong("1557127278000")
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "event_details" : { "eventA" : 2, "eventB" : 1, "eventC" : 2 } }
```

**Query analysis:**

- Grouping the data on the basis of `user_id` and `event` and calculating the count of that specific incident
- Grouping only on the basis of `user_id` and pushing event and its
  count into an array `event_details` as key-value pairs
- Converting the `event_details` into an object
- Applying the condition that the event count for ( A or B ) and C
  should be greater than 0
- Sum up individual event counts

Comment: Now I am getting result like this 

{
 "user_id" : "1",
 "event_details" : {
  "eventC" : 8,
  "eventA" : 1
 }
}
{
 "user_id" : "30",
 "event_details" : {
  "eventB" : 1,
  "eventC" : 8
 }
}


Can I get reult like this {
"event_details" : {
  "eventC" : 16,
  "eventA" : 1,
                "eventB" : 1,

 }

Comment: One more issue there are few more fields other than event on which I want to apply filter so suppose field is name and email. I have used {
    $project: {
      "user_id": 1,
      "event": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "email": 1,
    }
  }

but not getting result

Comment: @AkhileshJha Please update the question with actual data and the expected output... It would help us skip multiple iterations before coming to a actual solution.

Comment: @AkhileshJha at the end we are summing up counts of all types of events and thats irrespective of the user... then how can we also expect the user details at the end?

Comment: But as per my requirement I Need this. is there any way to achieve this

Comment: Lets say we have ```{ "user_id" : "1", "event_details" : { "eventC" : 8, "eventA" : 1 } } { "user_id" : "30", "event_details" : { "eventB" : 1, "eventC" : 8 } } ```
and we further aggregated it to  ```{ "event_details" : { "eventC" : 16, "eventA" : 1, "eventB" : 1, }```... which user info would be there at the end?